# customizing an attribute in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, css

This is my site. "www.silenttunes.net". I'm able to customize the CSS of all the elements on my page, except for one. "View all events".  I do not know why. Can someone please help. Below I've mentioned all the combinations I've tried.

```
 #aside p.tribe-events-widget-link a{
 font-size:12px;
 font-weight:100;
}

 p.tribe-events-widget-link a{
 font-size:12px;
 font-weight:100;
 }

 .tribe-events-widget-link a{
 font-size:12px;
 font-weight:100;
 }

 .tribe-events-widget-link {
 font-size:12px;
 font-weight:100;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inspecting your document with *Chrome Developer Tools* we see the following rules applied on your document.

```
.tribe-events-adv-list-widget .tribe-events-widget-link a,
.tribe-events-back a,
.tribe-events-list-widget .tribe-events-widget-link a, 
ul.tribe-events-sub-nav a {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

**Solution:** Add a more [specific CSS rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) like this:

```
aside.tribe-events-list-widget .tribe-events-widget-link a {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight:100;
}
```

---

**Note:** Adding `!important` behind a CSS rule also increases specifity. But it's suggested using this method only if there is no other possibility

```
tribe-events-list-widget .tribe-events-widget-link a {
    font-size: 12px !important;
    font-weight:100 !important;
}
```